# Changing NANO file saving location

Tags: gnome-terminal, nano

I know Nano saves the files in the current directory by default.
I know we can also specify the path we wanna save our file in.

What I wanna know is that can we select a save location in which nano saves all files by default?
Instead of specifying the path each time?

Is there like a config file for nano we can edit?

Comment: `info nano` will provide some details of nano's `nanorc` files; sorry I don't use it & that was the result of a 1 second `info nano` command; did you try and look  (*it is the 8th select-able option in the help/info page for my release of Lubuntu*)?

Comment: You can set an *operating directory* (`set operatingdir /path/to/dir`) in the nanorc file - not sure if that's what you're looking for (it will change the location for *opening* files as well as for saving them). See `man nanorc` or `info nanorc`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are inside the nano editor, pres Crtl+O (Oh not zero) and it will promt you
**File name to Write:** /youcantypepath/filenamekeeporchange
In fact if your terminal is expanded enough these shortcuts are always set as promts at the foot of the editor.